# how to install @vue/cli in laravel veu project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, command

I got these following errors while running `npm install -g @vue/cli`.

I am not sure what do these error messages mean, so any suggestion will be appreciated.

```sh
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',\
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/albiorix/.npm/_logs/2020-10-13T07_55_32_862Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` try this

Comment: `npm install -g @vue/cli` means let your node package manager (npm) to install `@vue/cli` package globally. Nothing is related to `laravel` here.

Comment: Have you installed node js?